# Setting the avatar in Material UI to actual size by styling child elements to full size of parent

Tags: css, material-ui, jsx

### General Question

How is the width and height for the elements inside Material-UI `<Avatar/>` set?

### Specific example

Specifically the challenge I am having is that `<AccountCircle/>` [example: account circle](https://www.materialui.co/icon/account-circle) is not filling up the parent.

I am trying to get an avatar of 80x80 but because material-ui adds so many random classes with random margins and padding, I end up with something else. The actual code generated produces an `<svg>` with a `<path>` inside which measures approximately 66.67px

```
const avatarImageStyle = {
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
};
```

#### JSX

```
<AccountCircle style={Object.assign({}, avatarImageStyle, {color: 'grey' })} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue on an application I am currently working on. I resolved it by increasing the `fontSize` of `Avatar` and then setting the icon to use its parent's font size.

We do not have to specify the width and height of the icon because Material-UI icons (and presumably, icons in general) are symmetric in shape. However, we do have to specify the dimensions of the Avatar, otherwise it will remain the same size as before while the size of the icon inside it will grow large (and the icon will be cropped). Since I use `fontSize` to increase the size of the contents of the Avatar, using `auto` for its dimensions will work.

So, for the style of the Avatar, use:

```
{
    fontSize: '80px',
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    ...
}
```

and to add your icon, use:

```
<AccountCircle style={Object.assign({color: 'grey' })} fontSize='inherit' />
```